# How to prevent a UITableViewCell being moved away from its own section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

My `UITableView` has 3 sections. Only the cells in the 2nd sections are movable:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL canMove = NO;
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        canMove = YES;
    }
    return canMove;
}
```

However, a cell (`B`) in the 2nd section (originally contains ``` A``B``C ``` cells) can be moved to the 1st section (originally contains only the `T` cell):

[image]

How can I make sure cells are moved *within* its own section?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if( sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section )
        return sourceIndexPath;
    else
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

From Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> This method allows customization of the target row for a particular
>   row as it is being moved up and down a table view. As the dragged row
>   hovers over a another row, the destination row slides downward to
>   visually make room for the relocation; this is the location identified
>   by proposedDestinationIndexPath.